# How start background periodic task with django-background-tasks

Tags: python, django

I want to create periodic task for check values in my `SQLite` file. I tried to create repeating task with django-background-tasks but it doesn't work. It works fine when I used `python manage.py process_tasks` in cmd. How start this task with start `django` and without use this command?

I develop my web app on Windows 10.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from client import tasks as task

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('client.urls')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
]

task.check_groups(repeat=10, repeat_until=None)
```

tasks.py

```
from background_task import background
from django.utils import timezone
from client.models import StudyGroup, Account

@background()
def check_groups():
    check_active_groups()
    check_inactive_groups()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> setup a cron task (or long running process) to execute the tasks

You have to setup cron or some other periodic runner to call that command because Django by itself will not be able to do this.